# in android studio, when i open a file that i downloaded from github ... it does not preserve the file tree hierachy

Tags: android

i am trying to make a phone call screening app.  many examples are given on the web.  Such as [https://github.com/a3r0id/BetterCallerID] every time i download them from github, and try to open them in Android Studio, Android Studio does not preserve the file structure.  so then Android Studio complains that i should migrate to gradle... which the original code was in...

i have both tried directly opening teh downloaded github app, and also have tried importing the code
so does anyone know why the file structure is not preserved when android studio opens files and folders, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to open the app folder. So let's say you are opening a project called DemoProject.. You take a clone of the DemoProject in your system .

Inside the DemoProject you are given with the app , gradle etc folders.

While opening you should open the DemoProject folder itself from within android studio and not the app folder.

The Gradle error is coming because the project level build.gradle is inside the DemoProject folder and not the app